# Java, regular expression catching multiple occurances of pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

This is my original String:

```
String response = "attributes[{"id":50,"name":super},{"id":55,"name":hello}]";
```

I'm trying to parse the String and extract all the `id` values e.g
50
55

```
Pattern idPattern = Pattern.compile("{\"id\":(.*),");
Matcher matcher = idPattern.matcher(response);

while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

When i try to print the value i get an exception:
`java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition`

Not had much experience with regular expressions in the past but cannot find a simple solution to this online.
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a greedy match operator like `*` with a `.` which matches any character. unnecessarily.
If you want the digits extracted, you can use `\d`.

```
"id":(\d+)
```

Within a Java String,

```
Pattern.compile("\"id\":(\\d+)");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Pattern.compile("\"id\":(\\d+)");
```

Answer (score 2):

`{` is a reserved character in regular expressions and should be escaped.

```
\{\"id\":(.*?),
```

Edit : If you're going to be working with JSON, you should consider using a dedicated JSON parser.  It will make your life much easier.  See [Parsing JSON Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java)

Comment: That `.*` is going to greedy match, is it not?

Comment: @Madbreaks Yep you're right - I glossed over that part and just thought he wanted to know why it was failing to compile

Comment: Is see you fixed it, removed my -1. :) Oops, it won't let me until you edit your answer, maybe put a note in it that you fixed it.