# Accessing nested fields in MongoDB documents using Spring Data Read Converters

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring Data with MongoDB and I'm having an issue accessing nested elements in my Mongo documents and convert those into Java fields. The following Spring query:

```
Query query = new Query().limit(1);
query.fields().include("a.d").exclude("_id");
mongoTemplate.find(query, MyObject.class);
```

returns the following DBObject:

```
{ "a" : { "d" : { "e" : 7.0 , "f" : 9.0}}}
```

I'm interested only in "e", and "f" so I decided to use a `Converter<DBObject, MyObject>`. Here is the my converter function:

```
public MyObject convert(DBObject dbObject) {

    DBObject dboA = (DBObject) dbObject.get("a");
    DBObject dboD = (DBObject) dboA.get("d");

    MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
    myObj.setE((Double) dboD.get("e"));
    myObj.setF((Double) dboD.get("f"));

    return myObj;
}
```

Suppose that I have nested documents with a depth of 20/30, my converter would be way to painful to write. Is there a way to do this that is less clumsy and more elegant?

Is it possible to do this with annotations? Something like `@Field(value = "a.d.e")`...

I feel like I'm missing something... Thanks!

Comment: I might would take a look into simple json to Obj converter. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365218/accessing-nested-fields-in-mongodb-documents-using-spring-data-read-converters But the next Step would be a reduction of the nesting level, since 20 to 30 is a lot.

Comment: Oh, yes.. dammit sorry! look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java

Comment: I would strongly recommend never nesting objects to that many levels in Mongo - if you feel you need to do so, I would suggest that this is poor schema design.  You will have difficulty querying and doing updates in multiple level embedded values.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Mongo themselves encourage nesting depending on the use case: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/  although I agree that 20/30 levels is excessive.

Comment: Thank you, I'm familiar with that document.  Note that examples all have levels of nesting that are 2/3 maximum, not 20 or 30 like you are asking about.