# conversion object to dictionary in `Java`

Tags: java, collections

conversion of an `XMLRPC` object to dictionary in `Java`

I have an object `obj={6=Coffee, 2=[Cocoa,icecream], 1=Chocolate}` and I want to convert this to a dictionary so that I can have key as 6, 2, 1 and values 'Coffee', 'Cocoa' and 'Chocolate'. How can I do this ? any pointers would be appreciated.

Object obj was returned by method of XMLRPC execute("execute", params);

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *an object `obj={6=Coffee, 2=Cocoa, 1=Chocolate}`*? Is it a string?

Comment: Is it a JSON object? If it is, check here http://stackoverflow.com/q/5015844/544983

Comment: I got this object through `XMLRPC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, "dictionaries" are called `Map`s. Refer to the various interfaces and implementations in [`java.util`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html). The main interface you'd probably want is [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Which implementation you want ([`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), et. al.) will depend on how you're using it. How you convert whatever it is you're starting with into a `Map` depends entirely on what you have to start with.