# Java Crowdflower API

Tags: java, api, web-applications, crowdflower

Does anybody know java wrapper for Crowdflower API. I have found so far only for Ruby.  I would really appreciate if anybody could point me out at least an example.

Comment: I implemented it myself. https://github.com/tivalex/java-CrowdFlower-

Answer (score 2):

The [CrowdFlower](http://crowdflower.com/docs/api) documentation page I found specifies that you send a URL and receive JSON output.

There are plenty of examples on Stack Overflow on how to parse JSON output in Java.

[Convert a JSON string to object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java)

[How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

[Parsing JSON Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java)

If you had something else in mind, you need to be way more specific in your question.  Like providing a link to the CrowdFlower page in question and pointing out the exact paragraph in the Crowdflower documentation that you're having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

We have developed java api's for crowdflower

do check it out

https://github.com/debarshri/jcrowdflower

Answer (score 1):

There is an article in the CrowdFlower Success Center that highlights two additional java interfaces for the CrowdFlower API: 1) https://github.com/sparkica/CrowdFlowerClient and 2) https://github.com/0xF013/CrowdFlowerJavaAPI