# How to convert json String with Square brackets to List?

Tags: java, json

I have the following string : `["LankaBell","BillDesk"]`

How can i convert it to Java List Object using using `json-lib-2.2.3-jdk15.jar\net\sf\json` library ?

EDIT : If not possible using this library then solution using other libraries is also appreciated.

Comment: what is the reason to convert only with that lib? why not use String methods ? Also show us your efforts

Comment: Follow this link:

It is helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java

Comment: @sanbhat In my product introducing new library is not that much easy.

Comment: Follow this link:

It is helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java

Comment: @MasterJ Thanks dear, but is it possible using the mention jar in my question or i have to switch to org.json

Comment: I do not know about it. But I use jackson-core-asl-1.8.5.jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the json-lib:

```
String source = "[\"LankaBell\",\"BillDesk\"]";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list = JSONArray.toList(JSONArray.fromObject(source), new Object(), new JsonConfig());
```

(Actually you can use just `JSONArray.toList(JSONArray.fromObject(source))` but it is deprecated)

Another non-deprecated solution:

```
list = (List<String>) JSONArray.toCollection(JSONArray.fromObject(source))
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me using the same library(net.sf.json..). i use this approach :
list = (List<String>) JSONArray.toCollection(JSONArray.fromObject(source))

Comment: Thanks Shylov. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) instead of json-lib.

```
List<String> list = new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper().readValue("[\"LankaBell\",\"BillDesk\"]", List.class);
```

Comment: I +1'd you, but you should really use the example with a generic Type for this.  You are not guaranteed to get a List<String> with your example!

Comment: Good point, @TomCarchrae. I assumed it would be safe enough for the array in question though. Obviously my code is not ideal (e.g. `ObjectMapper` should probably be reused, checked exceptions need to be handled, using parameterized type with casting issues might not be desirable vs using raw type, value to be deserialized would probably be a variable, etc), but it's a quick snippet of how easy it is to use Jackson.

Answer (score 2):

```
String input = "[\"LankaBell\",\"BillDesk\"]";

// net.sf.json.JSONArray
JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject(input);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Object o : jsonArray) {
    list.add((String) o);
}

log.debug(list);
```

Comment: @Yurii Shylov put more work into [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190001/how-to-convert-json-string-with-square-brackets-to-list/18190569#answer-18190382); his answer is superior.

Comment: Thanks daveloyall for redirecting to Yurii solution;+1 for your honesty

Answer (score 0):

```
    String string = "[\"LankaBell\",\"BillDesk\"]";

    //Remove square brackets
    string = string.substring(1, string.length()-1);

    //Remove qutation marks
    string.replaceAll("\"", "");

    //turn into array
    String[] array = string.split(",");

    //Turn into list
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);

    System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: How about `String string = "[\"LankaBell\",\"BillDesk\", \"one, two\"]";`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] objs = "[\"Lankabell\", \"BillDesk\"]".replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\"","").split(",");
```