# in Java, is is possible to parse a json object which is an array of arrays?

Tags: java, json

the answer chosen as the correct answer for this query:

=">Split JSON string into two variables

(assuming 'jsonStr' itself is an array streamed in from a php program, from which the variables are extracted),

Is there some way to use that or similar way to parse multidimensional arrays being streamed in?(i am not sure if I am using that term correctly, what I mean is arrays that contain arrays).

If I have the same object mappings in my java program as my php, I want to be able to repopulate the java objects array by array.

Sorry for reposting here but the question is really relevant since I have already used the solution, but wish to use it in a different way.

Comment: what are you using to parse your json?

Comment: `JSONObject myJSONObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);`

Comment: Give example in your question

Comment: What have you tried so far and what has been the result? This SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java has an example of how to get arrays using JSONObject. You need to provide more specifics in your question as to what your issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a parser like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), and you can parse any valid JSON.

Comment: How does Jackson compare to Gson and Flexjson?

Comment: You will of course get a million opinions, but mine is that there is nothing faster and easier to use than Jackson. Still, I suggest you try a few and see how you feel--particularly with regard to your array-based use case.

Comment: I had issues with Gson with nested structures; too much boiler plate code to get it working. Flexjson made things easy.

Comment: So then to answer your question, there are lots of options to parse JSON in Java!