# PHP return Json String into JsOnObject fail

Tags: java, php, json

this is php return json string

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
//echo $data;
//$obj = var_dump(json_decode($data));

$json = json_decode($data);


mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123456") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("db_shuttlebus") or die("Could not select database");

if (is_object($json)) {
    $d = array();
    foreach($json->details as $obj) {
        $Ticket_No = $obj->{'Ticket_No'};
        $Ticket_Date = $obj->{'Ticket_Date'};
        $Amount = $obj->{'Amount'};
        $In_Out = $obj->{'In_Out'};
        $Vehicle_ID = $obj->{'Vehicle_ID'};     
        $From_LocationID = $obj->{'From_LocationID'};
        $PriceType_ID = $obj->{'PriceType_ID'};
        $Trip_ID = $obj->{'Trip_ID'};
        $To_LocationID = $obj->{'To_LocationID'};
        $Inspector_Print = $obj->{'Inspector_Print'};
        $Driver_ID = $obj->{'Driver_ID'};
        $Updated_Time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $Route_ID = $obj->{'Route_ID'};
        //echo $_id;
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_ticket (Ticket_No,Ticket_Date,Amount,In_Out,Vehicle_ID,From_LocationID,PriceType_ID,Trip_ID,To_LocationID,Inspector_Print,Driver_ID,Updated_Time,Route_ID)VALUES('".$Ticket_No."','".$Ticket_Date."','".$Amount."','".$In_Out."','".$Vehicle_ID."','".$From_LocationID."','".$PriceType_ID."','".$Trip_ID."','".$To_LocationID."','".$Inspector_Print."','".$Driver_ID."','".$Updated_Time."','".$Route_ID."')";

        $rs = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query " . mysql_error());
            if ($rs) { 
                $d[] = array('Ticket_No' => $Ticket_No ,'Updated_Time' => $Updated_Time);
            }
            //break;
    }
    $pass_json = json_encode($d);
    echo $pass_json;

}
?>
```

this is my json String

```
[{"Ticket_No":1950,"Updated_Time":"2014-03-01 02:15:02"},
{"Ticket_No":1951,"Updated_Time":"2014-03-01 02:15:02"},
{"Ticket_No":1952,"Updated_Time":"2014-03-01 02:15:02"},
{"Ticket_No":1953,"Updated_Time":"2014-03-01 02:15:02"}]
```

i m trying to put my json string in JsonObject, and put in a map, then use a map to get the every row `Ticket_No` value, but unfortunately failed, how to let me json string into Jsonobject or jsonarray and loop the row get the `Ticket_No` and `Updated_Time` ?

```
     try {
           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
           Iterator keys = jsonObject.keys();
           Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
              while (keys.hasNext()) {
                 String key = (String) keys.next();
                 map.put(key, jsonObject.getString(key));
              }
           System.out.println(map);
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

**or**

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonstring);
                       JSONArray jsonPersonData = jsonArray.getJSONArray(1);
                       for (int i=0; i<jsonPersonData.length(); i++) {
                           JSONObject item = jsonPersonData.getJSONObject(i);
                           String Ticket_No = item.getString("Ticket_No");
                           Log.d(null,"Ticket_No= "+Ticket_No);
                           String Updated_Time = item.getString("Updated_Time");
                       }
```

also can't, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's not complete JSON, try doing

```
{"tickets": [ 
   {"Ticket_No":1950,"Updated_Time":"2014-03-01 02:15:02"},
   {"Ticket_No":1951,"Updated_Time":"2014-03-01 02:15:02"},
   {"Ticket_No":1952,"Updated_Time":"2014-03-01 02:15:02"},
   {"Ticket_No":1953,"Updated_Time":"2014-03-01 02:15:02"}
]}
```

I would suggest at the end of the for loop do something like this

```
$return_json = array('tickets' => array($d));
$pass_json = json_encode($return_json);
echo $pass_json;
```

Comment: No, i think this is correct json string, because is converted from php array to json http://my1.php.net/json_encode

Comment: You are going to have to look then how JSONObject expect it to look as well

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: `$d = array();` this is `$d`

Comment: For your java class, which json library are you using?

Comment: `import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;` this?

Comment: Here is an example of how org.json.JSONObject expects it to be

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{interests : [{interestKey:Dogs}, {interestKey:Cats}]}");

Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java

Comment: You still need it the way that I suggested in my solution

Comment: PHP can't return the json with header TAG, like urs `tickets` header tag. i have no idea how to add in

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: `{"tickets": [` this one, not the json header

Comment: The problem is that php does it the way you show and the java class you are using expects it the way I showed in my solution

Comment: I changed my answer, hopefully this fixes your issue.