# parse json values using java json parser

Tags: java

I have  a josn like this.From this how can i retrive platfrom and version values using java

code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws org.json.simple.parser.ParseException {

    try {
        // read the json file
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

josn

```
{
  "France24":[
    {
      "platform":"Linux",
      "version":"12.3",      
    }
  ],

   "Seloger":[
    {
      "platform":"windows",
      "version":"8",      
    }
  ],

  "Marmiton":[
   {
      "platform":"mac",
      "version":"10.1",

    }
  ]

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> platformLst = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> versionLst = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("France24");
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
    versionLst.add(obj.getString("platform"));
    platformLst .add(obj.getString("version"));
}
```

[Existing Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java)

[Example](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples)

[Simple Json Tutorial Link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)

Comment: @Psl, do you mean versionLst and platformLst is not getting populated?

Comment: getting error in place of ` JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("France24");`

Comment: Shouldn't be...Can you please share the exception details?

Comment: `The method getJSONArray(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.json.JSONObject to org.json.simple.JSONObject
 The method getString(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject
 The method getString(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject`

Comment: ok beacuse of you are using simple json where as you are importing org.json....check your import statment and correct those..also try using JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("France24");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56095/discussion-between-jayaram-pradhan-and-psl).

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("France24");
JSONObject france24Object = jArray.get(0);
String platform = france24Object.getString("platform");
String version = france24Object.getString("version");
```

Similarly, replace France24 with Seloger and Marmiton and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Like that:

```
JSONObject france = jsonObject.getJsonArray("France24").getJsonObject(0);
String platform = france.getString("platform");
String version = france.getString("version");
```