# How do I parse nested json object?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a json object in the following format in Java and I am not sure how to parse it?

```
{"status":0,
       "info":
       {"masterUuid":"12312312","X":"Y"}
}
```

Comment: please refer to the following post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java

Comment: I am not using json array for the second parameter. It's just a nested jsonobject. What can I do about that?

Comment: try to do something like this : "JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;" and then do the get on it like "array.get(1);"

Comment: how about if I have a string in this format and I want to parse? {"status":0,"x":"Y"}... assume this is what I am getting from the server side.