# Error while parsing JSON in Java

Tags: java, json

I am creating JSON using JavaScript as:

```
var myJson = '{'
    + '"name" : "myname",'
    + '"gender" :"' + gender
    + '"}';
```

However, while parsing it in Java using:

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) jParser.parse(myjson);
```

I am getting below error:

```
 (java.lang.ClassCastException) java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

Comment: Which library are you using JSONParser from? also, look at the signature of JSONParser.parse() method, most probably it is returning string. For other options, refer to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Answer (score 0):

by using a library, you can do it directly like this:

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(stringValue);
```

you can then iterate over the object.

https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java and for more details you can have a look at [Parsing JSON Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java)

Comment: I am using import org.json.simple.JSONObject;, so this won't work

Comment: yes, you need the api that does the parsing thing for you. You can check this out too --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java-me