# iterating through a JSON data with multiple levels of nested objects and arrays

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

i have being trying to parse through a JSON data in android and am looking for a code that can take the values out.JSON data structure is as shown below:

```
{
    "p":
        [
            {"t1":
                [
                    {
                        "key":"value", "key1":"value1"
                    },
                    {
                        "key":"value2","key1":"value3"
                    }
                ],
             "t2":
                [
                    {
                        "key":"value", "key1":"value1"
                    },
                    {
                        "key":"value2","key1":"value3"
                    }
                ],........
            }
        ]
}
```

that is my JSON data that i want to parse in android and the function that parses that data should return an array of all the values in in t1,t2 onwards but the array should not be an array of nested arrays or a nested array. please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON Object in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java)

Comment: A less crazy title

Answer (score 0):

put your json in ,[jsontopojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)!
it will generate model classes for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this , if you face any problem comment.

```
JSONObject jo=new JSONObject("YOUR JSON STRING");
JSONArray jsonArray = jo.getJSONArray("p");
JSONObject j1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
  for(int j=1;j<=j1.length();j++){
    JSONArray jArr1=j1.getJSONArray("t"+j);
      for(int i=0;i<jArr1.length();i++){
        JSONObject jsonObjectList=jArr1.getJSONObject(i);
        String key=jsonObjectList.getString("key");
        String key1=jsonObjectList.getString("key1");
    }
}
```