# Json parsing problems in Android Studio

Tags: android, arrays, json, api

I'm having some issues consuming a JSON API in Android Studio
I've been watching and reading about a lot of examples, but still can't figure out how to extract the data I need...

After some hours, I have finally gotten to the point were I figured to extract:

```
JSONObject subObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
```

With the following contents:

```
{
    "hereNow": {
    "count": 1,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "createdAt": xxxxxxxxxx,
        "type": "checkin",
        "timeZoneOffset": 60,
        "user": {
          "id": "xxxxxxx",
          "firstName": "xxxxxxxx",
          "lastName": "xxxxxxxxxx",
          "gender": "male",
          "relationship": "friend",
          "photo": {
            "prefix": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "suffix": "xxxxxxxxxx"
          }
        },
        "likes": {
          "count": 0,
          "groups": [

      ]
    },
    "like": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem now is: How to extract the user object? I've been trying a lot of things with

```
JSONObject
```

and

```
JSONArray
```

But I keep on getting this:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Can someone please help me?
Please don't redirect me to another topic, because in general I understand JSON, just not in this particular case...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try the example and read the [explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java/40828056#40828056) and update your question if you have doubts after reading

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
    try{
        JSONArray array = subObj.getJSONObject("hereNow").getJSONArray("items");
        for(int index=0; index<array.length();index++){
            JSONObject itemsObj = array.getJSONObject(index);
            JSONObject userObj = itemsObj.getJSONObject("user");
            Log.d("Test", "Relationship "+userObj.get("relationship"));
        }   
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Did this work? If yes upvote, so that others know it too who have similar problem.