# how to create json array from java string for loop

Tags: java, arrays, json, for-loop

I have a JAVA for loop which prints the out put as shown below.

```
inside for loop::{"state":"tess","path":"/content/projectpath/en/men"} inside for loop::{"state":"hello","path":"/content/projectpath/en/women"}
```

Any my code snippet is as shown below.

```
for (Value val : values) {
                    //jsonobj = new JSONObject(val.getString());
                    out.println("inside for loop::" + val.getString());
                  // JSONArray jsonarr = val.getString();
               }// out.println("::"+jsonobj.toString());
```

How to get a JSON Array after the for loop which should have the values `{"state":"tess","path":"/content/projectpath/en/men"}` and `{"state":"hello","path":"/content/projectpath/en/women"}`

Comment: Your JSON data should be parsed as a JSONObject, not a JSONArray because it's object data, not an array.

Comment: @TedHopp its a multi valued string array, which i will get from the JCR, which is required to formulate as JSON ARRAY

Comment: Okay. I reopened the question, as I thought it was about parsing. I see that @Kumaresan posted a workable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a JSONArray like this. insert your looping object on list. Finally you will get an array please try it.

```
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
list.add(val);
```

Comment: it gives me the **`The method add(String) is undefined for the type JSONArray`** error with `JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
                    list.add(val.getString());` code

Comment: JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
String response = "{"state":"tess","path":"/content/projectpath/en/men"}";

JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(response);

Comment: then add your object on list. refer thid link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java

Comment: Thank you, is there any possibility with `import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONArray` APIs for the same logic.

Comment: When you're using Apache Sling's version of `JSONArray`, instead of `add()`, the method is called `put()`.