# Mapping a JSONArray of dynamic JSONObject to java object in java

Tags: java

below written is my input json:

```
{
    "apiData": [{
        "apiName": "API",
        "arguments": [{
            "callFlow": "A"
        }, {
            "directoryName1": "CFAActivation"
        }, {
            "recDurationIVR1": "6000"
        }, {
            "numToDial": "*72"
        }, {
            "sleepDuration": "0000"
        }],
        "step": "1" 
    }]
}
```

//here "arguments" json array has dynamic json objects..

Comment: please let me know how to map it to an java object

Comment: need more clearification

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!! In arguments json array, the keys "callFlow", "directoryName1", "recDurationIVR1", "numToDial", "sleepDuration" will vary each time. so how can i create a java class for arguments?

Comment: See below Answer

Comment: isn't JsonArray here a java object in itself. You can iterate on it and work with its content using any Json Java library, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Respected Java Class According to your JSON

```
public class Arguments
 {
  private String callFlow;

     public String getCallFlow ()
    {
       return callFlow;
    }

    public void setCallFlow (String callFlow)
     {
    this.callFlow = callFlow;
     }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
    return "ClassPojo [callFlow = "+callFlow+"]";
    }
}


 public class ApiData
 {
   private Arguments[] arguments;

    private String apiName;

   private String step;

  public Arguments[] getArguments ()
{
    return arguments;
}

public void setArguments (Arguments[] arguments)
{
    this.arguments = arguments;
}

public String getApiName ()
{
    return apiName;
}

public void setApiName (String apiName)
{
    this.apiName = apiName;
}

public String getStep ()
{
    return step;
}

public void setStep (String step)
{
    this.step = step;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [arguments = "+arguments+", apiName = "+apiName+", step = "+step+"]";
}
}

 public class Jobj
{
private ApiData[] apiData;

public ApiData[] getApiData ()
{
    return apiData;
}

public void setApiData (ApiData[] apiData)
{
    this.apiData = apiData;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [apiData = "+apiData+"]";
}
}
```

Comment: In the above snippet, how the Arguments class would handle dynamic json structure?

Comment: you can see the getter and setter. in this class.

Comment: getter and setters are only for CallFlow attribute but as per the json, Arguments is actually an array with dynamic number of attributes.

Comment: bro  this is sample class according to your json. but if you want functionality then it might be same thing like this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java

Comment: you can use this class object to store your JSON object data correspondingly

Comment: Hi Negi Rox, for the next iteration the arguments array will be like given below
{
    "apiData": [{
        "apiName": "API",
        "arguments": [{
            "callerID": "2211"
        }, {
            "tune": "xxxx"
        }, {
            "rate": "6.0"
        }, {
            "number": "76"
        }, {
            "timeinterval": "57"
        }],
        "step": "1" 
    }]
}
so i need to create getter setter for all parameters (i.e) callerID, tune, rate, number, timeinterval?

Comment: json objects key will be varying each time. is there any method to map this to java  class object?

Comment: Then you need to store whole array as string in a db