# How to convert Optional<JsonObject> to List<String>

Tags: java

I have some api parameters which I have received from a json file in test method.   Now I need to convert this object to a list, because it contains arrays that I would like to handle individually.

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static Optional getQueryParametersTEST(JsonObject inputJsonObject) {
        JsonObject operators = inputJsonObject.getJsonObject("operators");
        JsonObject tez = operators.getJsonObject("tez");
        JsonArray parameters = tez.getJsonArray("parameters");

        Optional<JsonObject> queryParameters = parameters.stream().
            filter(JsonObject.class::isInstance).
            map(JsonObject.class::cast).
            filter(jsonObject -> jsonObject.getJsonObject("queryParameters") != null).
            map(item -> item.getJsonObject("queryParameters")).
            findFirst();

        return  queryParameters; 
    }
```

after i received queryParameters it comes in this format

```
Optional[{"priceMin":["0"],"priceMax":["150000"],"currency":["5561"],"hotelClassId":[""],"accommodationId":["158525","9002884","1"],"rAndBId":["15350","2424","2474","2749","5737","5738"]}
```

What can i do to get a list of Strings

I tried to perform a

```
return  queryParameters.ifPresent(newList::add)
            .flatMap(Optional::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Tried using this but   Jsonobject requires a source of string but i have queryParameters of type  Optional queryParameters 
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(my source should be the query param )

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("interests");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
        list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("interestKey"));
    }


    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{interests : [{interestKey:Dogs}, {interestKey:Cats}]}");

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("interests");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
        list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("interestKey"));
    }
```

Comment: You need to parse the JSON string properly. An API for that would be `jackson`

Comment: What should the List<String> contain? And why doesn't your method return a Optional<JsonObject>? Don't use raw types.

Comment: Use gson or jackson librararies to parse json object to java object.

Comment: @JBNizet list <String> should contains the output of the method as above i am getting [{"", ""}] i want to get a simple list so i can do a cartesian product with guava library

Comment: @SumeshTG can you show me an example if possible

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java

Comment: @SumeshTG mine json object is from vertx library would it work here with link you provided

Comment: Yes these libraries are compatable with any java application.

Comment: @SumeshTG i have updated my question to show you issue with using JsonOBJect what requires a source when i have query param the takes Optional<JsonObject>

Comment: I understood. In your case you are getting JSONArray . See the JSONArray  iteration ...

Comment: yes but how do i attach the object "queriparameter " to JSON OBJECT since json object accepts String in its constructor